# What is $\max(\operatorname{Re} \{ \frac{x^* Ax}{x^* x}:0 \ne x \in C^n\} )$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \left( \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2\\
0&1
\end{array} \right)$. What is $\max\left(\operatorname{Re} \left\{ \dfrac{x^* Ax}{x^* x}:0 \ne x \in C^n\right\} \right)$?

Answer (score 0):

If you write $x=(x_1, x_2)^t$, with $x_1=\alpha+i\beta$, $x_2=a+ib$, then you're looking for
$$1+2\cdot \max\{a\alpha+b\beta\}$$
given
$$(a^2+b^2)(\alpha^2+\beta^2)=1$$
And you can conclude with Cauchy-Schwarz